# How to click into the Quick Access toolbar to unload and load using Unit4 Excelerator?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I create a macro that allows the button to click onto the "Unit4 Excelerator" tab as shown in the screenshot, followed by it clicking unload and load.

The Unit4 Excelerator is software, which was added into Excel.
[image]

I tried recording the macro in the developers tab but it doesn't recognise the steps I take when clicking into the Quick Access toolbar. Perhaps it only works for the actual spreadsheet and there's meant to be another way to code using VBA?

I get this after recording the steps:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible to access functions through "ControlBar"
Example: Copy Selection

```
Sub TestContolExecution()

    CommandBars("Standard").Controls("Copy").Execute

End Sub
```

The trick is to figure out what the control's Name or ID is.
This is how I figured mine out:

```
Sub FindControlBars()
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 1 To 176
        Debug.Print CommandBars(I).Name
    Next I
End Sub
Sub FindControls()
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 1 To 17
        Debug.Print CommandBars("Standard").Controls(I).Caption
    Next I
End Sub
```